# How to create a third series based on two series

Tags: grafana, graphite

I'm using grafana with graphite. I have the issues timeseries graph where i get only incoming defects for a given day and how many of them are closed.

[image: Sample Data]

the outstanding formula is simple in excel (previous oustanding+ current incoming ) - current closed. But in graphite i dont know how to generate the outstanding series based on the incoming and closed. i tried all the defalult function but none of them work with the previous datapoint. Let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a timeshift or delay function on the outstanding series.